# Can the templates module handle multiple templates / directories?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I believe the Ansible [copy module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) can take a whole bunch of "files" and copy them in one hit. This I believe can be achieved by copying a directory recursively.

Can the Ansible [template module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) take a whole bunch of "templates" and deploy them in one hit? Is there such a thing as deploying a folder of templates and applying them recursively?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `template` module itself runs the action on a single file, but you can use `with_filetree` to loop recursively over a specified path:

```
- name: Ensure directory structure exists
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: '{{ templates_destination }}/{{ item.path }}'
    state: directory
  with_community.general.filetree: '{{ templates_source }}'
  when: item.state == 'directory'

- name: Ensure files are populated from templates
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: '{{ item.src }}'
    dest: '{{ templates_destination }}/{{ item.path }}'
  with_community.general.filetree: '{{ templates_source }}'
  when: item.state == 'file'
```

And for templates in a single directory you can use `with_fileglob`.

Comment: this answer is beyond useful, this answer is awesome! i've added my own answer to explain why (but have accepted this)

Comment: I love it when a plan comes together!

Answer (score 15):

This answer provides a working example of the approach laid down by @techraf

**with_fileglob** expects only files to live within the templates folder - see https://serverfault.com/questions/578544/deploying-a-folder-of-template-files-using-ansible

with_fileglob will only parse files in the templates folder

**with_filetree** maintains the directory structure when moving the template files to dest. It auto creates those directories for you at dest.

with_filetree will parse all files in the templates folder and nested directories

```
- name: Approve certs server directories
  file:
    state: directory
    dest: '~/{{ item.path }}'
  with_filetree: '../templates'
  when: item.state == 'directory'

- name: Approve certs server files
  template:
    src: '{{ item.src }}'
    dest: '~/{{ item.path }}'
  with_filetree: '../templates'
  when: item.state == 'file'
```

Essentially, think of this approach as copying and pasting a directory and all its contents from A to B and whilst doing so, parsing all templates.

Comment: only issue i had here was with the favicon which i had to copy over manually (it was corrupted when this did it) - you may argue why did i have a favicon in my templates folder ;)

Comment: Why do you need to pre-create the directories if "It auto creates those directories for you at dest"

Comment: Question: Does `with_filetree` also expect files to live within the templates folder?

Comment: Update: Just tested this and can confirm that `with_filetree` WILL WORK with any directory! So, it is *not* limited to just a `templates` directory.

Comment: does with_filetree overwrite directories if they already exist?

Answer (score 8):

I could not manage to do it with the other answers. This is what worked for me:

```
- name: Template all the templates and place them in the corresponding path
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ destination_path }}/{{ item.path | regex_replace('\\.j2$', '') }}"
    force: yes
  with_filetree: '{{ role_path }}/templates'
  when: item.state == 'file'
```

Comment: It seems with_filetree is not available anymore in ansible 2.11

Comment: @Cyril just tested with ansible v2.12.1 and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Cyril I see that too, I do not find it in the docs any more. Is there any official alternative?

Answer (score 4):

In my case folder contain both files and jinja2 templates.

```
- name: copy all directories recursively
  file: dest={{templates_dest_path}}/{{ item|replace(templates_src_path+'/', '') }}  state=directory       
  with_items: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'find '+ templates_src_path +'/ -type d').split('\n') }}"

- name: copy all files recursively
  copy: src={{ item }} dest={{templates_dest_path}}/{{ item|replace(templates_src_path+'/', '') }} 
  with_items: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'find '+ templates_src_path +'/  -type f -not -name *.j2 ').split('\n') }}"
  
- name: copy templates files recursively
  template: src={{ item }} dest={{templates_dest_path}}/{{ item|replace(templates_src_path+'/', '')|replace('.j2', '') }}  
  with_items: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'find '+ templates_src_path +'/*.j2 -type f').split('\n') }}"
```

Comment: Simple and working! Also without noisy verbose output like the FileTree
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I did it and it worked. \o/

```
- name: "Create file template"
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ your_dir_remoto }}/{{ item.dest }}"
  loop:
    - { src: '../templates/file1.yaml.j2', dest: 'file1.yaml' }
    - { src: '../templates/file2.yaml.j2', dest: 'file2.yaml' }
```